# Using a single JIRA Task ticket or create Sub-Tasks

Tags: testing, task, workflow, jira

We are using JIRA to work with a team of Developers and a QA team. Currently the 'Dev Team Leader' creates a 'Task' ticket, assigns it to the development member, who work on that ticket and then informs the JIRA ticket number to the QA team, who create a separate QA ticket for testing it. And of the test is pass or failed they inform the DEV team, who either fix it or change the ticket status to 'In Deploy'.

**My question is as follows:**

1. Should they create single ticket and use that to do the Development and Testing ? (ie. shift the ticket between the DEV Team and QA Team)
2. Should the DEV team create a Parent TASK ticket for Development and then assign it to the QA team, who will create a Sub-Task for the Testing and link it to the Parent Development ticket?

**Issues:**

1. We need to identify which team member worked on the development
   task?
2. Which team member worked on the Testing ?
3. How much of tie spent on Development as a whole?
4. How much of time spent on Testing as a whole?

**What is the best way of doing this ?**

Answer (score 2):

You only need one ticket or an Issue in JIRA context. Your Project should have a workflow with, for example, the following Statuses: `To Do` -> `In development` -> `In testing` -> from here, the Issue can go in two directions, back to `In development` if the QA is not satisfied or `Done`.

When the Issue is moved to the next step, it will/should be assigned to the proper person, i.e. in `To Do` it's assigned to your project lead or whoever distributes the tasks, `In Development` it's the developer, `In testing` the QA, etc.

This is the **most** widely-accepted way to use JIRA as a ticket tracker. Each transition will be recorded in the Issue Activity Log with the corresponding datetimes, Assignees, etc. You will have access to all the information you've asked for.

Comment: Can JIRA be configured to allow a single issue/ticket to track Development time separately from Testing time?  I've not been able to find documentation for how to do this.

Comment: @semaj, nope. There's a (paid) [plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213605/tracking-estimation-for-jira) for it, though

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the workflow is in need of granular tracking of development work and testing, where a single ticket (suggested idea) doesn't satisfy.

I found the following design useful:
1. Create a USER STORY that has a set of criteria that needs to be met.
2. Sub TASKS can be created as children of the STORY especially if they need to be worked on by different people. 
3. Once all tasks are completed, the USER STORY can be moved to TESTING / IN TESTING (whatever the workflow defines).
4. The QA/QE Engineer then can create TESTS / TEST CASES (children) for the User Stories and and execute them accordingly. Similarly, defects can be filed as BUGS as children of the story.

Ultimately in this workflow the story must meet a set of criteria and level of quality (based on what is acceptable to pass the story for the business) in order to be considered "completed" or ready for release.